# Rectangles in a chess board

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

How many rectangles can be made from the individual spaces of a chess board?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that, because it's asking about _rectangles_ and not just _squares_. I'll be quite surprised if the rectangle question isn't already on PSE, though.

Comment: OK, I think I'm surprised: I don't see any sign that this question has been asked here before. It's a bit of a maths-homework question, but I guess just about enough not so that I'm not about to close it.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, the question was originally about squares, but changed after I flagged it (see the edit).  But yes, rectangles are different so I'll retract my flag

Comment: Ah, OK. Hadn't noticed that the question had changed.

Comment: Dicul, in the future, if you change your puzzle after it's been flagged, let the flagger know.  I would have retracted the flag earlier

Comment: @Greg   I am pretty new here sir . I apologise for that

Comment: No problem, just trying to help out

Comment: Is a square considered a rectangle?  Should 1x1, 2x2, etc squares be excluded?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To specify a rectangle

> it suffices to say where its left and right boundaries are, and where its top and bottom boundaries are. There are $\binom92$ choices for each pair of boundaries and therefore $\binom92^2$ rectangles. That is to say, **1296 rectangles**.

Comment: It is amazing that this hasn't been done already on PSE!

Comment: Are we only counting rectangles whose edges are made from the lines on the board?  Because if you were to count all the rectangles possible by connecting corners between the squares, there's a lot more of them...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman As per the question these rectangles must be formed from "spaces".  Hence I would expect at minimum that no rectangle cuts through one of the spaces used to define it.  (The question of how many rectangles can be formed from an arbitrary group of points is perhaps more interesting than this one, though.)

Comment: Yes, the question becomes quite different (and I think much harder -- I suspect there is then no "elegant" solution) if you allow non-aligned rectangles. @Brilliand The question didn't always include the wording about "spaces" and may not have done when Darrel Hoffman wrote his comment.

Comment: Actually, it might not be that complex.  A valid rectangle shape would be one where the slope of each side is an integer ratio, where one dimension is a multiple of the other  (including a multiple of 1, which would be square), and where the sums of the two side lengths' rises and runs are <= board size.  Then simply multiply by board size - the difference between those values (in each dimension) for transpositions.

Comment: I don't mean they it would be difficult to, e.g., write a computer program to do the calculation. But I doubt there's a nice formula for the answer, as there is for axis-aligned rectangles.

Answer (score 13):

Of course @Gareth_McCaughan got this well-known puzzle immediately. But for people who aren't up on their combinatorics, here's the same calculation in a way that seems easier (at least to me).

1. There are 9x9 = 81 corners.
2. For each of these there are 8x8 = 64 corners that are not in the same row or column.
3. Each pair of these makes a rectangle.
4. But then each rectangle has been counted four times (you can have top-left and bottom-right or top-right and bottom-left and both of those can be done two ways)
5. So the final answer is 81 x 64/4 = 1296

Comment: You are physicist right?

Comment: Aren't you.....

Comment: I am. Or at least that's what I studied. I don't get to do too much now. Why?

Comment: I love physicists. Thinking you are one of them